# How to trigger update on AWS::Lex::BotVersion on stack update in cloudformation

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-lex

I'm using a lambda backed customresource to update some slots in my lexbot during stack update. I also have AWS::Lex::BotVersion resource in the same template. However, eventhough the DRAFT version of my bot has been modified, the bot version resource doesn't seem to also create new version (not triggered during stack update). How do make it so that whenever my lexbot is changed an update is also triggered on BotVersion resource forcing it to create a new version?

I've considered including some api calls to do the process of creating a new version and associating it with alias in my lambda itself, but i'm worried the lambda will get timed out since my bot contains upto 20 locales and combined with lamba code execution, building 20 locales, and creating a version takes more than 15 minutes which is max allowed execution time for a lambda function.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the primary identifier for the Lex::BotVersion resource, then it will replace the previous version.

Source: https://repost.aws/questions/QUTOwlgKSWQL6KSt-GxPWtgQ/aws-lex-botversion-does-not-create-other-versions-than-1